# How to use pandoc to convert wikitext to markdown with latex/mathjax/etc properly?

Tags: markdown, pandoc

I am trying to convert wikitext to markdown with latex/mathjax support.

I am using this command but the conversion is not too ideal as some parts have like this:

```
    :   $\mathbf{a} \cdot (\mathbf{b} + \mathbf{c}) = \mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{b} + \mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{c} .$
```

---

Answer:

```sh
pandoc --from mediawiki --to=markdown-definition_lists wiki.txt  -o wiki.md
```

with colons in front. Is this expected?

Comment: Can you add the input that got converted to the part you are showing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's expected if you are converting to pandoc's Markdown flavor. These colons are used in [definition lists](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#definition-lists). Use something like `--to=gfm` or `--to=commonmark` to get a more "standard" Markdown output, or disable unwanted extensions individually with `--to=markdown-definition_lists`.

Comment: Thank you! The disable worked, but the former two did not. Is there any precautions if I disable the unwanted extensions?

Comment: Things should just work after disabling the extensions.